Why does the query optimer choose a serial plan when filter made less restrictive
I'm working through Iztik Ben-Gan book T-SQL Querying.
I have some trouble understanding why making a filter less restrictive will make the optimzer move away from a parallel plan to a serial one.
The first query goes for a parallel plan, but the second goes for a serial one.
SELECT [orderid], [custid], [empid], [shipperid], [orderdate], [filler]
FROm dbo.Orders
WHERE orderid <=30000

SELECT [orderid], [custid], [empid], [shipperid], [orderdate], [filler]
FROm dbo.Orders
WHERE orderid <=490000

Both queries use this index in  for a Clustered index scans :
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [idx_cl_od] ON [dbo].[Orders]
(
    [orderdate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

The table has 1000000 rows with evenly distributed orderid's.
Anyone who knows the reason why?
Paralel plan with high rows numbers.

490000/1000000 is a much bigger percentage than 30000/1000000 and the clustered index isn't related to the predicate, consider indexing the orderid if that is commonly used in predicates

This is me guessing, but for the smaller subset of source rows in the result, the optimizer probably reckons that it's faster to do multiple searches and then concatenate the intermediate results whereas the merge overhead will be detrimental for the larger subset.

It would be helpful if you can post the query plans for each case.   You have a clustered index on orderdate (not orderid).  Your query is filtering on orderid.  So, you are looking at a scan of the table in each case (with pushed non-sargable predicate).  There are factors such as whether it gets a trivial plan (not the case for the first one, not sure about the second).  It could also be that the query is just not significant enough and the two plans cost out very close for this example.  Auto-param could be at play as well (showplan can help).

Parallelism has both costs and benefits.
The more rows that survive the filter the more have to be packeted up and sent across the exchange to the serial thread. This imposes a cost and there will be a tipping point where the serial plan is costed cheaper - i.e. the scale down in CPU costs for the plan operators running in parallel is outweighed by the additional cost of the extra parallelism operator(s).
The higher the DOP (degree of parallelism) or the narrower the estimated row size then the higher the tipping point will be here (in terms of estimated number of rows returned)

Let's assume the following table structure and example data...
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders](
    [orderid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [custid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [empid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [shipperid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [orderdate] [datetime] NOT NULL  INDEX [idx_cl_od] CLUSTERED,
    [filler] [varchar](8000) NOT NULL
) 

/*Generate some dummy rows of data*/
INSERT INTO dbo.Orders
SELECT value as [orderid], 
       1 as [custid], 
       1 as [empid], 
       1 as [shipperid], 
       getdate() as [orderdate], 
       'abcdefgh' as [filler]
FROM generate_series(1,10000000);

CREATE STATISTICS s_orderid ON dbo.Orders(orderid) WITH FULLSCAN;

On my machine with the above setup I see the tipping point being around 167.7K rows (with less than that I get a parallel plan with more than that I get a serial plan)
SELECT [orderid], [custid], [empid], [shipperid], [orderdate], [filler]
FROM dbo.Orders
WHERE 1=1 /*Prevent simple parameterisation*/ 
AND orderid <=167715; 

SELECT [orderid], [custid], [empid], [shipperid], [orderdate], [filler]
FROM dbo.Orders
WHERE 1=1 /*Prevent simple parameterisation*/ 
AND orderid <=167716; 


My machine has an available DOP of 4. If I add an OPTION(MAXDOP 2) I see a different tipping point of 55837 vs 55838 rows.
Why these tipping points?
The cost of the serial plan being compared is not sensitive to the selectivity of the filter in this case.
Whether I am using OrderId of 1 or 10,000,000 I see the same overall plan cost of ~ 75.54 for the following query
SELECT [orderid], [custid], [empid], [shipperid], [orderdate], [filler]
FROM dbo.Orders
WHERE 1=1 /*Prevent simple parameterisation*/ 
AND orderid <=10000000
OPTION (MAXDOP 1, QUERYTRACEON 9130) ; 

Comprised of the following elements

Clustered Index Scan I/O Cost 59.7402
Clustered Index Scan CPU Cost 11.0002
Filter operator CPU Cost 4.8

If I try forcing a parallel plan instead with a different hint OPTION(USE HINT('ENABLE_PARALLEL_PLAN_PREFERENCE'), MAXDOP 4, QUERYTRACEON 9130) I do see a different plan and some more variety in costs.



OrderId
Gather Streams CPU Cost
Filter CPU Cost
Clustered Index Scan CPU Cost
Clustered Index Scan IO Cost
Total




1
0.0287819
1.2
2.75004
59.7402
63.7190219


55837
3.96423
1.2
2.75004
59.7402
67.65447


55838
3.9643
1.2
2.75004
59.7402
67.65454


100000
7.07711
1.2
2.75004
59.7402
70.76735


167715
11.8501
1.2
2.75004
59.7402
75.54034


167716
11.8502
1.2
2.75004
59.7402
75.54044


200000
14.1257
1.2
2.75004
59.7402
77.81594



The above results show that the clustered index scan IO cost remains the same in the serial vs parallel plan and the CPU costs for the filter and clustered index scan were scaled down by a factor of 4 (reflecting the DOP) - 15.8002 * .75 is 11.85015 so the parallel plan is costed as cheaper until the row count going into the gather streams operator is enough for the operator cost to exceed that.
With hint OPTION(USE HINT('ENABLE_PARALLEL_PLAN_PREFERENCE'), MAXDOP 2, QUERYTRACEON 9130) the equivalent table is



OrderId
Gather Streams CPU Cost
Filter CPU Cost
Clustered Index Scan CPU Cost
Clustered Index Scan IO Cost
Total




1
0.0287819
2.4
5.50008
59.7402
67.6690619


55837
7.89997
2.4
5.50008
59.7402
75.54025


55838
7.90011
2.4
5.50008
59.7402
75.54039


100000
14.1257
2.4
5.50008
59.7402
81.76598


167715
23.6717
2.4
5.50008
59.7402
91.31198


167716
23.6718
2.4
5.50008
59.7402
91.31208


200000
28.223
2.4
5.50008
59.7402
95.86328



In this case the CPU costs for the operators running in parallel are only scaled down by 2 rather than 4.
15.8002 * .5 is 7.90010 so this is the tipping point for the gather streams operator cost before the serial plan looks cheaper.
The gather streams operator costs are also only scaled down by 2x rather than 4x so these are also larger than shown in the DOP 4 table for the equivalent row counts.
Additional Notes

The reason for using trace flag 9130 above is so we see the costs the optimiser uses when comparing plans and don't lose information about the costs for the filter in a post optimization rewrite.
The estimated row size for this setup is very wide (4035 bytes) due to the Filler column being varchar(8000). If the estimated row size is reduced the estimated costs for the Gather Streams operator for a given estimated row count will similarly reduce meaning the tipping point will be higher.


Good answer, thanks

@SveinungTyssedal - I ended up rewriting the whole thing anyway to hopefully make some aspects clearer
